# Table name not found AD_USERPREFERENCE idempiere

Tags: idempiere

I have deployed new `idempiere` in eclipse luna 32 bit.
At login time it throws following error

> "table name not found ad_userpreference"

.

Answer (score 1):

Your database does not have all scripts updated.
the table ad_userpreference is created in this script [201504231737_IDEMPIERE-2556.sql](https://bitbucket.org/idempiere/idempiere/src/cbaff96d59d9238dc202f14030402b32be56f3da/migration/i2.1z/postgresql/201504231737_IDEMPIERE-2556.sql)

You can clone this repository and re-import the seed, located inside

> org.adempiere.server-feature\data\seed

After import, use migrate_postgresql.sh inside directory \migration\ .

Now your database have all necessary scripts to run without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error. If the table is present and it says its not found, it means that the user you are using to access the db is not assigned to the DB